# Different results for selector/signature and web3 JS request

Tags: web3js, ether

Internet!
Can someone tell me why I have different results for:

```
function abiSelectorPuzzleWallet() external pure returns (bytes memory) {
    return abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256(bytes("multicall(bytes[])"))), [0xd0e30db0]); 
}

function abiSignaturePuzzleWallet() external pure returns (bytes memory) {
    return abi.encodeWithSignature("multicall(bytes[])", [0xd0e30db0]);
} //0xac9650d800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0e30db0
```

And through web3 JS request:

```
depositData = await contract.methods["deposit()"].request().then(v => v.data)
'0xd0e30db0' //same
multicallData = await contract.methods["multicall(bytes[])"].request([depositData]).then(v => v.data)

'0xac9650d80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d0e30db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
//looks similar, but not same
```

Am I doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
function abiSignaturePuzzleWallet() external pure returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes[] memory array = new bytes[](1);
    array[0] = hex"d0e30db0";

    return abi.encodeWithSignature("multicall(bytes[])", array);
}
```

Note that `[bytes(hex"d0e30db0")]` is not correct either.

To be precise, `hex"d0e30db0"` is a string literal, where `bytes(hex"d0e30db0")` is of type `bytes`, but there's an implicit conversion so the casting is not necessary in the code above.

We can't use `[bytes(hex"d0e30db0")]` because that would be of type `bytes[1]`, i.e. a *static array*. The square brackets always represent static arrays. We need to explicitly create a dynamic `bytes[]` array and populate it.

If you want to see the type of a non-trivial expression, just try to assigned it to, say, `uint ok` and look at the error msg. For instance,

```
uint ok = [bytes(hex"d0e30db0")];
```

gives this error: "Type **bytes[1]** memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still don't get why I have to do it in such a way. Is there any reference in the docs/any more detailed topics?
Btw why is hex"d0e30db0" not correct?

Comment: @0x0f0f0f I updated my answer. See if it helps.